# Is $\forall A \in \mathcal R: P(A)$ equivalent to $\{A \in \mathcal R: P(A)\} = \mathcal R$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose I want to  prove the $ \forall A \in \mathcal{R}, $statement
$ P(A)  $ holds. Now consider the set

$$ \mathcal{K} = \{ A \in \mathcal{R} : P(A) \; \text{holds}\}$$

my question is: is it enough to show that $\mathcal{R} = \mathcal{K}$ to solve the problem above? If so, why?

thanks

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall x; (x \in\mathcal{K} \implies x \in \mathcal{R} \land P(x)) \\  \forall x;(x\in \mathcal{K} \implies P(x)) \text{ (1)}\\
\mathcal{R}=\mathcal{K} \implies \forall x; (x\in\mathcal{R}\implies x\in\mathcal{K})\text{ (2)}  \\ \mathcal{R}=\mathcal{K} \implies \forall x; (x\in\mathcal{R}\implies P(x)) \text{ using (1) and (2)}$

Comment: I'm afraid I can't make sense of this.  What does "$\forall x \in \mathcal{K} \implies ...$" mean?  The antecedent is not even a formula.

Comment: @TrevorWilson I hope it is fixed now.

Comment: Yes, it looks good now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is enough.
Sets in Set theory are equal if they have the same elements. Now imagine you have this K == R. It means that every A in R belongs to K, that is, satisfies P.

(And I have to learn to use this beautiful notation that you use.)

Comment: By the way, it is not necessary to use the axiom of extensionality (which says that if two sets have the same elements, then they are equal.)  All we need here is the converse statement "if two sets are equal, then they have the same elements", which is a logical tautology because if two things are equal then _everything_ about them is the same.

Comment: For some basic information about writing maths on this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Answer (score 0):

You have $K$ being the subset of $R$ on which $P$ holds. If $R=K$, then $P$ must hold on all of $R$, as required.

For a formal proof, just make the substitution $R$ for $K$. No need to invoke extensionality. Something along the lines of:

Suppose $\forall a (a\in K \iff a\in R \land P(a))$ and $R=K$.

Substituting, $\forall a (a\in R \iff a\in R \land P(a))$.

Suppose $x\in R$. Then $P(x)$. 
Generalizing, we have $\forall a (a\in R \implies P(a))$ as required.